# Discord.js v12 role.delete() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So, i was testing this out, and that when I use this code, it doesn't actually delete the roles, is this a bug?
On the code:

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  message.guild.roles.fetch()
    .then(r => r.forEach(s => 
      s.delete()
    ));
})
```

I tried other variants as well such as:

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  message.guild.roles.cache.forEach(r => r.delete());
});
```

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  message.guild.roles.cache
    .map(r => r.id)
    .forEach(s => 
      message.guild.roles.cache.find(l => l.id === s)
        .delete()
    );
});
```

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  const roles = message.guild.roles.cache
    .map(r => r.id);
  for (m=0;m<roles.length;m++) {
    message.guild.roles.cache.find(s => s.id === roles[m])
      .delete();
  }
});
```

I even tried to not mass delete and just delete one:

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.find(s => s.id === 'ROLE_ID')
  .delete();
```

None seemed to have worked, and they all return the same error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined
```

or

```
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Role
```

Though I'm 100% sure that the role does exist and is valid. This error only happens when I try to delete roles. When I tried checking the roles in the server using

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.map(r => r.id);
```

it sometimes returns a blank array, though there `are` roles in the server.

Comment: Which exact version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: `discord.js^12.3.1` It's the current latest one. That's why I use `.cache` as well. Wait... didn't I write this in the title..? I don't think there's much difference between `v12.1.x`, `v12.2.x`, and `v12.3.x`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the reason for this is because Discord Guilds have default roles, mainly, @everyone, and one with the bots name, which you can't delete.

I don't know exactly how to differentiate these "default" roles from created ones, but it seems like @everyone role seems to be always `Role.rawPosition`= 0 and the bots roles likes to take the last position of this same index. Also throughout my testing, seems like bot roles have `Role.editable` = false. Created ones, but also @everyone, has it = true. Which makes things a little confusing.

With that in mind, it's up to you to create the best algorithm for what you're trying to achieve. But I can promise it's unsafe.

If you can *if* yourself to roles that can be deleted, Node shouldn't crash.

[image]
(CURA GAMER BOT is my test bot, so the first role was not manually created)

I'd recommend you to log all your roles cache, at least for testing, and check the roles properties in other to find out what will suit you better. Whatever if your doubt was if  `role.delete()` was reliable, yes it seems like. But I'd recommend deleting a single role at time, having the reference to its objects anyway.

Here are some tests that worked for me (screenshot scenario) which may or may not work for you (use at your own risk):

```js
const roles = message.guild.roles.cache;

roles.forEach(role => {
  // -1 because I have only on bot role
  if(role.rawPosition > 0 && role.rawPosition < (roles.size - 1)) {
    role.delete();
  }
});
```

```js
const roles = message.guild.roles.cache;

roles.forEach(role => {
  if(role.editable && role.name !== '@everyone') {
    role.delete();
  }
});
```

The safest for me, delete based on timestamp:

```
const roles = message.guild.roles.cache;

roles.forEach(role => {
  // Created after Tue Sep 08 2020 15:55:00 GMT-0500
  if(role.createdTimestamp > 1599598514000) {
    role.delete();
  }
});
```

Comment: I've described in the question, that I've tried this with single roles deletion rather than mass deletion. It seems that it didn't work, and though I agree this might be the issue, it isn't mine as I've just tested it out and it didn't work.

Comment: Hm... through my testing it worked fine. Maybe bot ain't got enough permissions?

Comment: I mean, it shouldn't return a type error like the role is undefined in any of those scenarios but the ```Invalid Role``` maybe could be something related to it? (Try logging the events: ```roleDelete```, ```error``` or ```invalidated```)

Comment: Nothing, it doesn't work at all and my bot does have permission `2146958847`. @GabrielAndrade

Answer (score 0):

That's because [`Collection.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=delete) requires a `key`, not an `object`. Instead of passing the role *object* as an argument, you should be passing the role snowflake.

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.delete('<Role ID>')
```

---

Also, to delete all roles, you can use the [`Collection.clear()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=clear) method, which removes all elements from the collection.

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.clear()
```

Comment: As a side note, `Guild.roles.cache.delete('key')` or `Guild.roles.cache.clear()` only delete the roles from the Cache, not the actual Role object in the Guild.

Comment: Did not work, I [tried deleting a role](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/701700878540734494/752501845607317505/unknown.png) and it still [exists](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/701700878540734494/752502656894894080/unknown.png).

Comment: Ah, @Jakye I suppose that's why it's returning empty arrays instead.

Comment: You should try [`.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=fetch) instead, as that should delete the roles and not just the cache

Comment: @Lioness100 I **did**, it's the first codeblock I gave. I also tried fetching it separately (by itself, not mass) and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Ok, that's really weird. I just tried most of the methods you showed in your question, and they all worked for me

Comment: The comments are getting too long,.. We should move to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221095/discussion-between-mineko-kayui-and-lioness100).